# Easy derivation for area of obtuse triangle

Tags: geometry, education, area

I am looking for an **easy** derivation for the area of an obtuse triangle. As everybody knows the formula for any triangle is the same: half the product of the base and its height.

The derivation for an acute triangle is quite neat and purely geometrical (you draw a rectangle twice the size of the triangle and are done).

I am looking for an equally simple derivation for the area of an obtuse triangle.

Just to be clear I don't have a problem deriving this in all kinds of ways (including using integrals). However the simplest I found would still require either to solve a set of linear equations or the distributive law.

Is it possible to do it without these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse at $A$, and orient the plane so $AB$ is our base. Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$ extended through $A$, say with foot $F$. Define $G,\,H$ so $FBGC,\,FAHC$ are rectangles. Then $$[\triangle ABC]=[\triangle FBC]-[\triangle FAC]=\frac{[\square FBGC]-[\square FAHC]}{2}=\frac{[\square ABGH]}{2}.$$(Sorry for using a square symbol for rectangles.) But $ABGH$ has the same base and height as $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: Thanks. Actually that's what I had, written with products of distances, forcing me to use the distributive law in the last step of your equations. But of course the distributive law has exactly the geometrical interpretation that you give.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a similar argument for obtuse triangles
[image]
**Hint**

$$[\Delta ABC]=\frac{[EBDC]}{2}-[\Delta EAC]$$

Answer (score 1):

The area of an obtuse triangle with base $b$ and a point $p$ that is a distance $h$ above the base but a distance $c$ outside it, is equal to the area of the right-angled triangle with base $b+c$ and height $h$, minus the area of the right-angled triangle with base $c$ and height $h$.